# Swift: Do, Try, Catch block and if optional statement produces a thread ending nil value

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Even though I have a do-try-catch block and an if-optional within that block, a nil value still ends my thread. Here is my code:

```
do {
        if let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as? NSDictionary //error is on this line
            // use jsonData
        {
            return jsonData
        } else {
            if let _ = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                print("5")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("3")
        // report error
    }
```

This method returns a `NSDictionary?` which is an optional too.

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: the first if statement, but only if I'm not connected to WIFI

Comment: See answer below. It's work for you. Avoid force unwrapping if you not sure about it. And your code not clear. Statement in `If/else` is same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also check for nil in data instead of force-unwrapping it, e.g.:

```
do {
    if let data = data {
        if let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, ...
```